# Exclude *.pyd files from go to definition (with ctrl+click)

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pyd, pyi

I have a small problem with my Eclipse IDE PyDev plugin - when I'm developing a program using Python with libraries in *.pyd format, I can't go to definition, because It's binary format. But there are corresponding *.pyi files with source code. How to "force" PyDev to use *.pyi files instead of *.pyd files for Go To Definition?